# SIP tool to generate test traffic and measure latency

Tags: voip, sip-server

I'm looking for a tool (preferably open source) which could generate test traffic towards a SIP server, test traffic could be SIP INVITE/OPTIONS ping and verify the response from SIP server.
I also need the tool to provide some stats on the response to INVITE/OPTIONS message sent for testing, I need this information to verify my SIP server is up and I can use the average response time duration to get an estimate of the real time performance of the SIP server.
It would be great if I can connect the tool to a backend, to get the stats in a DB, this will greatly help in retrieving the stats.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the most popular one which is [SIPp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/) but you may have a hard time connecting it to a DB. Alternatively you can also use [SIPUnit](https://github.com/RestComm/sipunit) if you're familiar with Java programming which would allow you to connect to a DB more easily